# Bulk edit form onsave javascript ignored

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to run onsave javascript on Dynamics CRM Bulk Edit form for entity `opportunity`.

I modified customizations as follows:

```
<event name="onsave" application="false" active="true" BehaviorInBulkEditForm="Enabled">
          <Handlers>
            <Handler functionName="Form_onsave" libraryName="new_opportunity_onsave.js" handlerUniqueId="{05e2ece2-0dcd-8b4c-3c11-4d0e3acdd694}" enabled="true" parameters="" passExecutionContext="false" />
          </Handlers>
        </event>
```

where `form_onsave` is following function

```
function Form_onsave() {
alert ("BULK");
}
```

But when I save form, no alert is displayed.
This method of using `BehaviorInBulkEditForm="Enabled"` works for `onload`/`onchang`e events, but doesn't work for `onsave`. What am I missing?

MS CRM 2011 Premise UR 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from MS:
Javascript run on onload/onchange events but  this behaivor is explicitly not documented, not supported, problematic and may be removed at any time without notice.

Javascript doesn't run on onsave event in 2011.

However, this behaivor DO work in 2013 (although unsupported at least since 4.0), so I think using this trick is pretty safe.

Answer (score 1):

The SDK says the following about BehaviorInBulkEditForm:

*BehaviorInBulkEditForm: Not used. All scripts are disabled for bulk edit forms.*

So, js's won't run while bulk editing. Unfortunately.

Comment: Johan, thanks for answer. I'm fully aware that this is unsupported configuration, but onload/onchange works in CRM 2011 and onsave worked in CRM 4.0.